# What should the capacitor values be for the 2n3904 transistor to operate in the mid gain?

Tags: transistors, amplifier, bjt, frequency

What should the capacitor values be for the 2n3904 transistor to operate in the mid gain?
[image]

Comment: What does mid gain mean in your case? Are you aware that your resistance values are not realistic, you can't have that precision and such values do not exist.

Comment: Values for coupling and bypass capacitors depend on the lowest frequency that circuit would be operating at. This would be the low cutoff frequency and you’d need to know this beforehand.

Comment: Normally, the input and output coupling capacitors are large enough so that they present "negligible" impedance to the lowest signal of interest. Use the usual \$X_\text{C}\$ computation for that purpose. However, you may want to include a capacitor (keeping it really simple and not even close to "best practice") on the collector resistor to "kill" some of the AC gain at frequencies higher than of interest. I also agree that your resistor values need to be of sensible precision.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I learned that it would be sufficient to have 1/10 of the resistance element against impedance (1 / π * f * c) in ac analysis, thanks to everyone.